# Reactivesearch and Elasticsearch: CORS error

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm new about using ES and I found this reactsearch I can use with.

I'm trying to make a query call and I have :

```
export const Logging = (props: ILoggingProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ReactiveBase
                url="http://localhost:9200"
                app="fluentd"
                enableAppbase={false}
            >
                {/* Our components will go over here */}
                <DataSearch
                    componentId="searchbox"
                    dataField={"level"}
                />
            </ReactiveBase>

        </div>
    )
}
```

when I make a search I receive error in the call:

> `_msearch /fluentd/_msearch   POST + Preflight    Error CORS`

So I deduce that it is a CORS problem. How can I solve?

EDIT:

I have set in my elasticsearch.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mySiteName-elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    # volumes:
    #   - ~/volumes/jhipster/mySiteName/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
      - 127.0.0.1:9300:9300
    environment:
      - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m'
      - 'discovery.type=single-node'
     http.cors.enabled : true // 
    http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
    http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
    http.cors.allow-headers : "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution.